# IgnoreRoute and specific controllers for page requests in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

Let's say I have a PagesController for my frontend pages and when someone requests a slug, the general route is:

```
Route::get( '{slug}', 'PagesController@show' );
```

But I also have two specific routes in my frontend which are handled by different controllers:

```
Route::get( '/login', 'UsersController@index' );
```

and

```
Route::get( '/register', 'RegistrationController@create' );
```

So, I want to create exceptions for both static pages when they get requested. I made some research and someone with a similar problem was suggested to go ahead and create two different middlewares because he had Pages and Users, but that's not my case, I have just two exceptions to the rule here and I want those two special cases treated different. Right now I have the show method taking care of the special cases with if/else statements (because for some reason the specific routes are not getting called, even if I switch the {slug} route to the bottom), but I want the best possible solution. My code looks like this (it will use the $request variable when it is properly implemented)...

```
    public function show( Request $request ){
        $uri = $request->path();
        if( $uri == 'login' ){
            return view( 'auth.login' );
        }
        elseif( $uri == 'register' ){
            return view( 'registration.register' );
        }
        return view( 'Pages::show' );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're suggesting is not the way to do this.

When Laravel handles a request, it will attempt to match the request URI against your application routes in the order they're registered. Therefore, you simply need to include the `login` and `register` routes before the `page` route in your `routes/web.php` file.

```
Route::get( '/login', 'UsersController@index' );
Route::get( '/register', 'RegistrationController@create' );
Route::get( '{slug}', 'PagesController@show' );
```